# Material UI Card Height

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm sure I'm missing something easy here but I can't figure this out for the life of me.

- I am using [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/) card components in React to display
  albums with track lists. The cards are expandable and are filling
  100% of their parent container so that when one card is expanded
  they all expand in height.
- How can I stop the other cards from expanding with their parent
  element and get them to stay at just enough height to show the
  content?

Only the expanded card should change height.
Here is a screenshot of what I mean: [material-ui cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmFbO.jpg)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can apply styles to card.

```
 var cardStyle = {
    display: 'block',
    width: '30vw',
    transitionDuration: '0.3s',
    height: '45vw'
}
```

And in your CardStyle you can apply the above styling by

```
  <Card style={cardStyle}>
                <CardHeader
                  title="URL Avatar"
                  subtitle="Subtitle"
                  avatar="https://placeimg.com/800/450/nature"
                />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am actually already applying a style to the card. What height property would I use to get the card to adjust to show its content? I am using ```height: auto``` but that is causing the card to fill the entire row height.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was that I needed to change the height of the parent div and not the card component. Thank you for helping!!

Comment: Just accepted. Thank you again for your input. Sorry for the delay I am still new to posting on StackExchange.